# Error message about Windows 10 even though I'm on Windows 10

Tags: miktex, windows

I'm trying to use pdfinfo, but when I run it, I get the following error message:

> MiKTeX requires Windows 10 (or greater): https://miktex.org/announcement/legacy-windows-deprecation

This is odd since I'm running Windows 11 Home.

**The output of pdfinfo is ok. I just keep getting this annoying message.**

Running miktex.exe --version tells me I'm using the latest version: MiKTeX 24.1.

Comment: It is only a message not an error. I get it on windows 11 too. Report it here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: So happy to read this question! Nowadays I do not use Windows (lack of access to a machine with privileges), but I had Windows 10 when it was new. I am currently writing a custom document class that benefits from Linux subsystem support in Windows 10 or later, and was wondering how many MiKTeX users are not on 10. Well, if MiKTeX is dropping support for pre-10, all good.